# Dynamically Change Y-Axis Field in Encoding Based on Selection Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

How can I dynamically change a data field encoded for the y-axis based upon a selection? I am trying to build a visualization to display event count data over the 24 hours of a day, and I want the user to be able to select different timezones (e.g. EST, CST, MST, or PST).

To do this, I have built out a single selection where I specify all the options I list above in the parentheses, with EST being set as my default. I want to create a condition where when I chose another option besides EST, I see the visualization dynamically update. I've explored creating other hour fields specifically for those timeframes, or adding in condition logic to try to account for these dynamic changes, but I have not arrived at a good solution yet. Can anyone help out?

Here is an example of what a few lines of my data look like

```
"data": {
      "values": [
        {
          "title_column":"example",
          "Type": "Technology",
          "Events": "100",
          "Hour": "0",
          "Date": "9/1/20",
          "Time Period": "Last Time"
        },
        {
          "title_column":"example",
          "Type": "Technology",
          "Events": "110",
          "Hour": "1",
          "Date": "9/1/20",
          "Time Period": "Last Time"
        },
```

and the visualization looks like this when it is put together, with it dynamically updating based on the selection:

[image: Time of Day Image]

And when my code is static, it looks like this:

```
    "layer":[
           {"mark":{
               "type":"bar",
               "point":true,
               "color":"#FFC94E",
               "height":15
           },
           "selection": {
        "timezone": {
          "type": "single",
          "init": {"changer": "EST"},
          "bind": {
            "changer": {"input": "select",
              "options": ["EST","CST (-1 Hour)","MST (-2 Hours)","PST (-3 Hours)"]}
          }
        }
      },
    "encoding":
        {
            "x":{"field":"Events",
            "type":"quantitative",
            "aggregate":"sum",
            "axis":null},
            "y": {"field":"Hour",
            "type":"ordinal",
            "axis":{
              "labelSeparation":1,
              "labelPadding":4,
              "title":null
            }
            }
        }}]
        }
```

However, focusing in particular on the **y encoding** of the bottom part of the code, I would ideally like to make that dynamic. I'm thinking I could create calculations for each of the timezones and then write a condition that works like the following below, but I have not been able to get this to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
"y": {
            "condition": { 
            "selection": {"timezone" : "EST"},
            "datum": "datum.Hour"
              }
            "condition": { 
            "selection": {"timezone" : "CST (-1 Hour)"},
            "datum": "datum.Hour_CST"
              }
              ...
            }
```

Here is the link to my code:
[vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVCY6guAH0obSwnno4ADyQIOM6KIAAqAJ44cGhhcLCyHmxk4SEAoqSymDboAIx6IQASbAwATjE6IQAiRtHoAJwEOQQATBVKoTQIcAAEAApwJexqMQAySBCY3R1dIAC+Cg5Oru6e3iB+AUHR7ZG1sfGJyWkZWTE5eYXFZblVNTENTa0h0z39g2zD6GMTU53R84tMM43B4GF4YhtAsEdlEYqE4jAEoIkiklOk4JlsiAck8lEVSjFmrdMHsHi02mE-n0BkNRuNJi85gsQI4gctQeCfP4odswrs4QikSjjhjTrldJcCegtMTSY1yc8qW9aV96b8ZgCWUsQasIdyts9+eh4QdkUc0ScsTkxBT8dcQGJZfd5bjKV1qe9PiBvgy-kzAcCVmC1pCDTC9ibEYdUSB0ZizgBWW1XGIJp31F0Ul4elXetWMzWswMckP66F82HGwXRkXx3IANmTUpA9fTIDJruzyo+dJ+BeZRfZuq5m3LEUr+yjZpjcbF2IA7E37fO2x2s0qaT3VX2-YXtUHOesy7zxxHq9Pa3OcgAOJcxa+rzOK93dr0+9X-Af7kt60cno2TkK5qxpaZx1He9SPo864vpub75ruX5sjqwa-jyhoTpGQEzqB6CtBB2IUtUJLOtBz6vHBva+hqSHFsOR5-hhZ6msKFqilizQXHiKa5DkUEKu0G6elRH7+lqyEHqWjHhgKLHAbOHGunaZxEkoxFymRgmwcJ27UZ+AZDqhI7oTJVZyTh7GEhK3HNjkMpqXcGaaW6FE6XmO40QZKGHqGY4AVhNZsXWIDNDakr2ta-GdkJubvv2XmSWhYYVsxU6sSBll4Um4WJlFMGubFCGeeJdFGQxJkpbJaXybhIWNjlDZ5eROZbu5eliYO3lSRVp5Vdhl4cYuDULk1WkFa1cWIQlP7GclvVmdVFnBc0t7DTeo0uS18EefpJWGT5x5MX1gUZct4FrXUG1dpRumiXuEkzeVc3+ee6UKTEugEa66mkQJm2viJ8V7V1SV+Zhr01ZlIBaFxIDKXhfEOSRTl-ddbmTcVnWJbNYOpf1QVzloSk8SFqkgD9KPRdphU7R1370b5-7g+ZA0fdZcMk809nk457ZPmNW2A1NwPY09uMxAAsmwJSYBQZA9AASnAABmNCyEgshQLy73oGI3PwyARG82uzUA7dQNY49jNHegUsy3Lisq2rGta6z6AJvrJOIzzyN885aM0+192lQd0mVbb0uy0g8vdErqvq5r2u1fWnvNmTFN+6jMUTUVu2Wwzh2mSAdtRzHcfO4nbsgPOqf2tzGcmwLZttXdtH7d1z0TiXDux07CeuwTWLXrXMSOkjGlZ9TOe08H7eg0zezd9Hjvxy7SdQ3UI-u1d2fbUHbcgzjC+S5HPfl-36-BXkW8tjvU976300F2H83F6fy+96vleD2cdnDSu49fpU3Gg-C29MyrWyLkvMufc15VxxDfB8gDKb5UFubYW+cIGF3Dm-e2H9z5wJ-uKG+l1kGZ2AWgluYCHrPx6gBaBK8K4D1OlePWa0ja+0bv9G6VCMHgNDnQru78YFf2YTrbEHs1rewbvzbh6Nc50xoVgl+9DhGMIvvAlOa107G1kQHae+8n7KMEYvNRn8mGXyvDXNa9ddH+13kLTG-CO7iwjngkRFj4HDzWmPH2E8KHNwxnnZx88ba4NLuowhLCrSbzWmmMhXD9GgL4UogRndTHuMid-aJhIdA3xyK2BJeiHHoKcaklxx83ERPMRoohIU-42QigAvxQDUGBIUbPQ+YtKnhLPrA7J4jmhczWkglpKDTY8KCYokOFSwkMJqVEwZWh8mkLGeQtpkyOkH1FpAnB8yCEDNqqFG+307GTxAY44J5TQlQLMQcsRRzJGNMJNIs5ATNkz22VbbBr99n9IeVDZoWjnl4R0Zw4p99LnTLnkfOZdz-mWMGic2x4L7GQtKVcmZNy9lmIAOIYgGBYKuWhCkc2bBw-xGz5GfKMWk1xvSP74tkISwQVcxCkoNq81F5zKFTM6Tsn5qjMndCZSyquHLOZ3wuRi6FXTdm-LxQSkoRK6kFOGiiylEzqWGJFt8lRQjhWiuVayupQLhq+JkWi6VvCylYthbcw1SqVU5OlBK5s8S1mJJKTazFMLulwsdcy41bK3X2lJZanl7SaW6toekk+gaxV1ITKGmIzSI3vO1Y-GNxi41VJ7ka514j6wpvQKM9NVLA5ZswXSnp8yC0mpddXEt7YpW8q2bS2ZDrqn1qrteZtsNy1asrdQu1-qu35qdQ28RdR+1cs1U3D5Orq2dpxQm4NqqdD9rBfOuRw6UmjvlUK7tk74FqpBdiDVrSh0GKrSE+1q7j1BsLbVHE-aLVvIrTekdfrD0GsfYmxtdl+0esHQuzN365WCr-ROp9U6X3srWuGj917km2p-VBjJ-712AeTWtNNyGwN7rQ5B-VmGYMAfEQU-tZaCO7q-fu9DpH41YefVDHI85+2rNA3R1DvqSMmOY+R7DlG+3DVOdyjNRG+MCqY3mxlJ7VUzrE3Oq9hH6PEZkwJuTMce2ms3WJ7dqmeNQv5XqrTDKdMKcbZxZtwyilWrbdG5d2LX4BQvHU8656KXOmaJGnhvQShwGIOwBgEBugAHU4BwAANays07mwCJ1KM6A9Zyx8vnJOtQC0FkLYXIsxbi2ZhLbm3ovuJmndLfm3LZeC8UPLUXYumdjfSkrkMr5aFSyTS9GYMufq9DV3LEWGuFeaz01rS0rzZXPe+8FvWUMxAG3VobBWms5paxDCbVp6ydfdZVzL-XAu1dC8txrXzRthPG14giSHZtVdzIt47+XTsdpcy9FmimdvLj231hbh3BtPZG2tsbG2q6cQIjR27+3fs5aWwD1bNaLsg9Nc0T79xvvzfQA9+rK2ztA8R+96zYVz0Dt0XNtTB2YePeG-DldrmkfWYTKj3i6PyfQ6O9j572aEdF0u6aoaxPDM9bu1lv7sPqe4+5zg3n1nrxM4vSz4zmPRdU5xy9+9dOCfiM+j4hXSS2f-fF2rsdUv6da5yHL83uvvVY5O4DyXGvFrEvZpym7coyeK5ADbuHEvadvcd3UrQYgLf4chz9pXlOOd2998zf3jaSUEXWkU93evw-s9tzT17Mf8Zx-nBbrjpPhcU7T97o3v68ZJdqloTzZL7Tibd4X-XYvVdc+j+X9zjabRy84lb9FnvleR4z+rv32fxFiHK7XwXfNk-W-7+nn3me2+lahnrLv3Wp8N9Twb5vzmh-QfwQip3w1vNC6h5vpvnOd-G4VcK+5iLR6jLS0njffeI9z9LxhwT+-RF3-QMCmvhIe9rUvdDcW8F9P8PFalG15wH8utADKFgDt870r8j0+lv8q5Ylps4Dm4ECL8kCy9wCskAUr4dAYDdsn9T8X9i8QDL98DtNCCf9sQ7N-9f8sD-NZ8S9QDd8yMv9PFVUtBSCvtyCw9KCt9cDrkuCCCFlDk2MnlmCQAId68KCcCo8wC6CpCiCrx6wBC0chCMcRDz8VCJC1Db8vF8lj918lD2DqC8CP9jCD9FNtDmddDWcz8VcxCD1bCLN6DQcGk5CcRWDqsrDEDxDkC98IDFkjkVobEAj7sgj3DGNzM-k0DTU2FicZtFDhDlDB9QjuDwjpDloExHCJEYiRdX8OCaDPCkjeDrNrFidXcfNn8sj58jCvD1CGCVoij2MSii9RDDCcjJCTCA88kRlujG83C+jaDWjBi49E8-D89Q89Cmj39ZMpj7C49lkxNzCGhp9e8ljOD+i7Dki48xAiju9nCPc9iKiViqjICtc-8DYhlRjXCB9miDjVijitdoCxM19tjGi4iJjKjFVYNQdm0tiWg-iyjrCQjJi60rNR9vZH9PVwTLDITgiPDrigSKNk4xMnj9DxjsiYTMThMjkETYDziU88SXjljEiiTWNgoSVzVcTLibCMS106S5wExSSyCkSdigD-iCTAS2S4MoZi1hp6iT9Mj+TXjCShTe0uTBCeSISqC0SEiEtYTgSPNm0FCGiUTlT4j+M1TaThSr5zhhp5iMjFipTqTDTZTVUzVicwTeT4CrT9iZSWNjTWF5Tf4mSXSriaTbScMt0fTUT9T4t6V1SsS2N5wvTxRgy9SATWT3SvE304zeiBTEyhN2SOIdAYzijySZ8QyEz-SkzTUz0-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).

Comment: Here is the link to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selections can only filter on column values, not column names. Fortunately, you can convert column names to column values by using a [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html).

To accomplish what you want, I'd suggest the following:

- Use a series of [Calculate Transforms](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) to calculate new columns containing the values you want to show.
- Use a [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) to stack these values into a single column with an associated key column.
- Link the selection binding to the key column created in the fold transform.
- Use a [Filter Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/filter.html) to filter the values based on the selection
- Finally, add a row encoding so that the selected column is labeled on the axis.

Put together, it looks like this ([open in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1K1STClShiSQQzgQ0AbVCY6guAH0obSwnno4ADyQIOM6KIAAqAJ44cGhhcLCyHmxk4SEAoqSymDboAIx6IQASbAwATjE6IQAiRtHoAJwEOQQATBVKoTQIcAAEAApwJexqMQAySBCY3R1dIAC+Cg5Oru6e3iB+AUHR7ZG1sfGJyWkZWTE5eYXFZblVNTENTa0h0z39g2zD6GMTU53R84tMM43B4GF4YhtAsEdlEYqE4jAEoIkiklOk4JlsiAck8lEVSjFmrdMHsHi02mE-n0BkNRuNJi85gsQI4gctQeCfP4odswrs4QikSjjhjTrldJcCegtMTSY1yc8qW9aV96b8ZgCWUsQasIdyts9+eh4QdkUc0ScsTkxBT8dcQGJZfd5bjKV1qe9PiBvgy-kzAcCVmC1pCDTC9ibEYdUSB0ZizgBWW1XGIJp31F0Ul4elXetWMzWswMckP66F82HGwXRkXx3IANmTUpA9fTIDJruzyo+dJ+BeZRfZuq5m3LEUr+yjZpjcbF2IA7E37fO2x2s0qaT3VX2-YXtUHOesy7zxxHq9Pa3OcgAOJcxa+rzOK93dr0+9X-Af7kt60cno2TkK5qxpaZx1He9SPo864vpub75ruX5sjqwa-jyhoTpGQEzqB6CtBB2IUtUJLOtBz6vHBva+hqSHFsOR5-hhZ6msKFqilizQXHiKa5DkUEKu0G6elRH7+lqyEHqWjHhgKLHAbOHGunaZxEkoxFymRgmwcJ27UZ+AZDqhI7oTJVZyTh7GEhK3HNjkMpqXcGaaW6FE6XmO40QZKGHqGY4AVhNZsXWIDNDakr2ta-GdkJubvv2XmSWhYYVsxU6sSBll4Um4WJlFMGubFCGeeJdFGQxJkpbJaXybhIWNjlDZ5eROZbu5eliYO3lSRVp5Vdhl4cYuDULk1WkFa1cWIQlP7GclvVmdVFnBc0t7DTeo0uS18EefpJWGT5x5MX1gUZct4FrXUG1dpRumiXuEkzeVc3+ee6UKTEugEa66mkQJm2viJ8V7V1SV+Zhr01ZlIBaFxIDKXhfEOSRTl-ddbmTcVnWJbNYOpf1QVzloSk8SFqkgD9KPRdphU7R1370b5-7g+ZA0fdZcMk809nk457ZPmNW2A1NwPY09uMxAAsmwJSYBQZA9AASnAABmNCyEgshQLy73oGI3PwyARG82uzUA7dQNY49jNHegUsy3Lisq2rGta6z6AJvrJOIzzyN885aM0+192lQd0mVbb0uy0g8vdErqvq5r2u1fWnvNmTFN+6jMUTUVu2Wwzh2mSAdtRzHcfO4nbsgPOqf2tzGcmwLZttXdtH7d1z0TiXDux07CeuwTWLXrXMSOkjGlZ9TOe08H7eg0zezd9Hjvxy7SdQ3UI-u1d2fbUHbcgzjC+S5HPfl-36-BXkW8tjvU976300F2H83F6fy+96vleD2cdnDSu49fpU3Gg-C29MyrWyLkvMufc15VxxDfB8gDKb5UFubYW+cIGF3Dm-e2H9z5wJ-uKG+l1kGZ2AWgluYCHrPx6gBaBK8K4D1OlePWa0ja+0bv9G6VCMHgNDnQru78YFf2YTrbEHs1rewbvzbh6Nc50xoVgl+9DhGMIvvAlOa107G1kQHae+8n7KMEYvNRn8mGXyvDXNa9ddH+13kLTG-CO7iwjngkRFj4HDzWmPH2E8KHNwxnnZx88ba4NLuowhLCrSbzWmmMhXD9GgL4UogRndTHuMid-aJhIdA3xyK2BJeiHHoKcaklxx83ERPMRoohIU-42QigAvxQDUGBIUbPQ+YtKnhLPrA7J4jmhczWkglpKDTY8KCYokOFSwkMJqVEwZWh8mkLGeQtpkyOkH1FpAnB8yCEDNqqFG+307GTxAY44J5TQlQLMQcsRRzJGNMJNIs5ATNkz22VbbBr99n9IeVDZoWjnl4R0Zw4p99LnTLnkfOZdz-mWMGic2x4L7GQtKVcmZNy9lmIAOIYgGBYKuWhCkc2bBw-xGz5GfKMWk1xvSP74tkISwQVcxCkoNq81F5zKFTM6Tsn5qjMndCZSyquHLOZ3wuRi6FXTdm-LxQSkoRK6kFOGiiylEzqWGJFt8lRQjhWiuVayupQLhq+JkWi6VvCylYthbcw1SqVU5OlBK5s8S1mJJKTazFMLulwsdcy41bK3X2lJZanl7SaW6toekk+gaxV1ITKGmIzSI3vO1Y-GNxi41VJ7ka514j6wpvQKM9NVLA5ZswXSnp8yC0mpddXEt7YpW8q2bS2ZDrqn1qrteZtsNy1asrdQu1-qu35qdQ28RdR+1cs1U3D5Orq2dpxQm4NqqdD9rBfOuRw6UmjvlUK7tk74FqpBdiDVrSh0GKrSE+1q7j1BsLbVHE-aLVvIrTekdfrD0GsfYmxtdl+0esHQuzN365WCr-ROp9U6X3srWuGj917km2p-VBjJ-712AeTWtNNyGwN7rQ5B-VmGYMAfEQU-tZaCO7q-fu9DpH41YefVDHI85+2rNA3R1DvqSMmOY+R7DlG+3DVOdyjNRG+MCqY3mxlJ7VUzrE3Oq9hH6PEZkwJuTMce2ms3WJ7dqmeNQv5XqrTDKdMKcbZxZtwyilWrbdG5d2LX4BQvHU8656KXOmaJGnhvQShwGIOwBgEBugAHU4BwAANays07mwCJ1KM6A9Zyx8vnJOtQC0FkLYXIsxbi2ZhLbm3ovuJmndLfm3LZeC8UPLUXYumdjfSkrkMr5aFSyTS9GYMufq9DV3LEWGuFeaz01rS0rzZXPe+8FvWUMxAG3VobBWms5paxDCbVp6ydfdZVzL-XAu1dC8txrXzRthPG14giSHZtVdzIt47+XTsdpcy9FmimdvLj231hbh3BtPZG2tsbG2q6cQIjR27+3fs5aWwD1bNaLsg9Nc0T79xvvzfQA9+rK2ztA8R+96zYVz0Dt0XNtTB2YePeG-DldrmkfWYTKj3i6PyfQ6O9j572aEdF0u6aoaxPDM9bu1lv7sPqe4+5zg3n1nrxM4vSz4zmPRdU5xy9+9dOCfiM+j4hXSS2f-fF2rsdUv6da5yHL83uvvVY5O4DyXGvFrEvZpym7coyeK5ADbuHEvadvcd3UrQYgLf4chz9pXlOOd2998zf3jaSUEXWkU93evw-s9tzT17Mf8Zx-nBbrjpPhcU7T97o3v68ZJdqloTzZL7Tibd4X-XYvVdc+j+X9zjabRy84lb9FnvleR4z+rv32fxFiHK7XwXfNk-W-7+nn3me2+lahnrLv3Wp8N9Twb5vzmh-QfwQip3w1vNC6h5vpvnOd-G4VcK+5iLR6jLS0njffeI9z9LxhwT+-RF3-QMCmvhIe9rUvdDcW8F9P8PFalG15wH8utADKFgDt870r8j0+lv8q5Ylps4Dm4ECL8kCy9wCskAUr4dAYDdsn9T8X9i8QDL98DtNCCf9sQ7N-9f8sD-NZ8S9QDd8yMv9PFVUtBSCvtyCw9KCt9cDrkuCCCFlDk2MnlmCQAId68KCcCo8wC6CpCiCrx6wBC0chCMcRDz8VCJC1Db8vF8lj918lD2DqC8CP9jCD9FNtDmddDWcz8VcxCD1bCLN6DQcGk5CcRWDqsrDEDxDkC98IDFkjkVobEAj7sgj3DGNzM-k0DTU2FicZtFDhDlDB9QjuDwjpDloExHCJEYiRdX8OCaDPCkjeDrNrFidXcfNn8sj58jCvD1CGCVoij2MSii9RDDCcjJCTCA88kRlujG83C+jaDWjBi49E8-D89Q89Cmj39ZMpj7C49lkxNzCGhp9e8ljOD+i7Dki48xAiju9nCPc9iKiViqjICtc-8DYhlRjXCB9miDjVijitdoCxM19tjGi4iJjKjFVYNQdm0tiWg-iyjrCQjJi60rNR9vZH9PVwTLDITgiPDrigSKNk4xMnj9DxjsiYTMThMjkETYDziU88SXjljEiiTWNgoSVzVcTLibCMS106S5wExSSyCkSdigD-iCTAS2S4MoZi1hp6iT9Mj+TXjCShTe0uTBCeSISqC0SEiEtYTgSPNm0FCGiUTlT4j+M1TaThSr5zhhp5iMjFipTqTDTZTVUzVicwTeT4CrT9iZSWNjTWF5Tf4mSXSriaTbScMt0fTUT9T4t6V1SsS2N5wvTxRgy9SATWT3SvE304zeiBTEyhN2SOIdAYzijySZ8QyEz-SkzTUz0-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-CuAHAa6nGhK1AHIJQfmwC3oJANQDmsgNAMQNGpYNAamwQWmx8koNgZQRGgCpm2q-qkqicBIBAZ2BtQcNWmmo6oAA)):

```json
{
  "width": 300,
  "data": {
    "values": [...]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"field": "Time Period", "equal": "Last Time"}},
    {"calculate": "datum.Hour - 0", "as": "EST"},
    {"calculate": "datum.Hour - 1", "as": "CST (-1 Hour)"},
    {"calculate": "datum.Hour - 2", "as": "MST (-2 Hours)"},
    {"calculate": "datum.Hour - 3", "as": "PST (-3 Hours)"},
    {
      "fold": ["EST", "CST (-1 Hour)", "MST (-2 Hours)", "PST (-3 Hours)"],
      "as": ["Zone", "Hour"]
    },
    {"filter": {"selection": "timezone"}}
  ],
  "selection": {
    "timezone": {
      "type": "single",
      "init": {"Zone": "EST"},
      "bind": {
        "Zone": {
          "name": "timezone",
          "input": "select",
          "options": [
            "EST",
            "CST (-1 Hour)",
            "MST (-2 Hours)",
            "PST (-3 Hours)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "point": true, "color": "#FFC94E", "height": 15},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Events",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "axis": null
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Hour",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {"labelSeparation": 1, "labelPadding": 4, "title": null}
    },
    "row": {
      "field": "Zone",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": null
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you