# Altair: how do I get the values from a dropdown menu

Tags: altair

[image]

Here is the code for generating the image:

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=['Brand','Function','Category'])
selection = alt.selection_single(name='Color By', fields=['categories'], bind=input_dropdown)
alt.Chart(df_PCs).mark_circle().encode(x="PC1:Q", y="PC2:Q", color="Function:N", tooltip=['Name']).add_selection(selection)
```

What I want to do is to color the dots either by Brand, Function or Category whatever the value that comes from the dropdown menu. Is there a way to get the value of the dropdown menu? Such as selection.value()?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this is similar to the Vega-Lite answer in [Dynamically Change Y-Axis Field in Encoding Based on Selection Vega-Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449715/dynamically-change-y-axis-field-in-encoding-based-on-selection-vega-lite)

Selections cannot filter on column titles, only on column values. Fortunately, you can use the [fold transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html) to stack multiple columns and turn those column names into column values.

Here is an example of a Fold Transform in conjunction with a selection box to choose which column to color by:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randn(100),
    'y': np.random.randn(100),
    'c1': np.random.randint(0, 3, 100),
    'c2': np.random.randint(0, 3, 100),
    'c3': np.random.randint(0, 3, 100),
})

selector = alt.selection_single(
    name='Color by',
    fields=['column'],
    bind=alt.binding_select(options=['c1', 'c2', 'c3']),
    init={'column': 'c1'}
)

alt.Chart(df).transform_fold(
    ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], as_=['column', 'value']
).transform_filter(
    selector
).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    color='value:Q',
    column='column:N'
).add_selection(
    selector
)
```

[image]

For your data, it might look like this (though I've been unable to test it because the data is not included in the question)

```python
selection = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['column'],
    bind=alt.binding_select(
        name="Color by: ",
        options=['Brand','Function','Category']
    ),
    init={'column':'Function'}
)

alt.Chart(df_PCs).transform_fold(
    ["Brand", "Function", "Category"],
    as_=['column', 'value']
).transform_filter(
    selection
).mark_point().encode(
    x="PC1:Q",
    y="PC2:Q",
    color="value:N",
    column="column:N",
    tooltip=['Name:N']
).add_selection(selection)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried on my data, but it's not working. I wonder if it is because you used numerical data points for your color and I have categorical data?

Comment: Please edit your question to add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the error.

Comment: I've added a further example that is based on the data shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized there was a stupid bug in my attempt to reproduce your code...